# node.js sync request within two for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to make my code sync , because google blocking if we send too much request as async.

```
for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
     (function(e,u){
    console.log(titles[e]+" - "+filter[u]);
    request('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?  client=chrome&output=json&hl=tr&q='+ titles[e] +" "+filter[u] ,{"json":true,"encoding":"binary"}, function (error, response, tags) {
        console.log(tags.toString());
     });

    }(i,j));

    }
  }
```

this code works properly but it is async , i know how to do it with one loop but two loops i do not know .

Comment: No. Google doesn't block your requests because they are async. Google might block them because they are too many, too fast, too parallel, and rate-limits them.

Comment: Can you show us what you would do with one loop? Then we'll be able to help you extending the concept to a second loop.

Comment: I want to send sync request  within two loop , it is clear . Moreover , i know that why google blocking me , because of that i want to make my code sync.  if i use one loop it won't enough for me at this situation

Comment: Simply making it synchronous likely will not solve your rate limiting problem, depending on what the rate is and how fast the requests complete. An asynchronous solution where it sends the requests in series would be far more effective.

Comment: if i make it synchronous , i can set delay time for each request

Comment: No, you can't, because you're in a for loop. unless, you wanted to make it asynchronous! putting it in a setTimeout would effectively be making at least part of it asynchronous, thus going against your sync requirement.

Comment: @OsmanErdi: You can use delays in asynchronous code as well… (in fact, much easier even)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try use [`async.js`](https://github.com/caolan/async) with [`eachSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eachSeries), like so

```
var requests = [];

for (var i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
    requests.push({title: titles[i], filter: filter[j]});
  }
}

async.eachSeries(requests, function (req, next) {
    request('http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&output=json&hl=tr&q=' + req.title + " " + req.filter, {
        json: true,
        encoding: 'binary'
    }, function(error, response, tags) {
        console.log(tags.toString());

        next(error);
    });
}, function () {
  console.log('done');
});
```

> The next iterator is only called once the current one has completed.
>   This means the iterator functions will complete in order.

Comment: Thank you so much , i was know async.js but i didn't use it like this before.

Comment: How can i finish loop if statusCode != 200 ?

Comment: Oh it is very logical , i choosed hard way and fail , thank you again :)